# Tesseract parse image and return null

Tags: android, tesseract

I have problem in tesseract method. i use below code and my application directly stop.Below is my `jni.cpp` file.

```
struct native_data_t {
    native_data_t() : image_obj(NULL), image_buffer(NULL) {}
    tesseract::TessBaseAPI api;
    jbyteArray image_obj;
    jbyte* image_buffer;
    int width, height, bpp;
    char bBWFilter;                 // 0=disable, 1=enable
    char bHorizontalDisplay;
};
native_data_t *nat = get_native_data(env, thiz);
if (nat->api.Init("/sdcard/","eng")) {
        LOGE("could not initialize tesseract!");
        res = JNI_FALSE;
    }
```

can you help me?And what is datapath in this init method? thanks in advance.

my LogCat is as below.

```
09-03 11:52:53.186: VERBOSE/MLOG: AssetsManager.java:(2263): isAssetsInstalled(): Assets are already correctly installed
09-03 11:52:53.186: VERBOSE/MLOG: OCR.java:(2263): GetLanguage(): eng
09-03 11:52:53.206: VERBOSE/MLOG: OCR.java:(2263): setLanguage to eng
09-03 11:52:53.206: VERBOSE/MLOG: OCR.java:(2263): noLangs=1
09-03 11:52:53.206: VERBOSE/OcrLib(native)(2263): ocr_open
09-03 11:52:53.206: INFO/OcrLib(native)(2263): lang eng
09-03 11:52:53.246: ERROR/OcrLib(native)(2263): IN BASE CPP
09-03 11:52:53.246: ERROR/OcrLib(native)(2263): IN 2nd if BASE CPP
09-03 11:52:53.326: INFO/ActivityThread(2253): Publishing provider com.google.android.maps.SearchHistoryProvider: com.google.googlenav.provider.SearchHistoryProvider
09-03 11:52:54.076: INFO/ActivityManager(123): Start proc com.android.voicedialer for broadcast com.android.voicedialer/.VoiceDialerReceiver: pid=2274 uid=10016 gids={3002}
09-03 11:52:54.206: INFO/ActivityManager(123): Stopping service: com.android.vending/.util.WorkService
09-03 11:52:54.336: INFO/ActivityManager(123): Process com.temp.unique.ocr (pid 2263) has died.
09-03 11:52:54.366: DEBUG/Zygote(122): Process 2263 exited cleanly (1)
09-03 11:52:54.756: INFO/dalvikvm(2274): Debugger thread not active, ignoring DDM send (t=0x41504e4d l=38)
09-03 11:52:54.766: DEBUG/vending(261): [43] LocalAssetCache.updateOnePackage(): No local info for com.temp.unique.ocr
```

and my package is `com.temp.unique.ocr`. My application process is directly died.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's already a JNI wrapper for Tesseract 2.04 named [Tesjeract](http://code.google.com/p/tesjeract/). You may want to look at its source code to see how they did it.

The datapath is the path to [tessdata](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/ReadMe) folder, which contains all the language data files.

There's also a JNA-based solution named [Tess4J](http://tess4j.sf.net), if you're interested.

Comment: I just want to know why my application process is directly died? It's not give force close error but directly process died and come home screen.

Comment: Is tessdata folder under /sdcard path?

Tess4J is JNA based; it runs on Windows. I'm not sure about Android.

Comment: Check out another JNI wrapper for Tesseract on Android. http://www.itwizard.ro/interfacing-cc-libraries-via-jni-example-tesseract-163.html

Comment: now every thing fine because i haven't add eng.trainneddata file in tessdata folder but now, when i call `nat->api.End();` i get same error as in my logcat.